# How do I 'register' local domain names, e.g. just on my home NT domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, domain-name

I have just set up a small server for testing, using SBS 2003.  I have set it up as a domain controller, and my dev machine belongs to that domain.  One of the first things I wish to test is a scenario where HTTP requests under many domain names access sub-directories of a single parent site.

Both my dev machine and domain controller are both currently set up to use my ISP's DNS, but I think I will need to set the DC up to use the ISP one, and my dev machine to use a DNS on my DC server.  Is this a good option?  How do I make my dev machine think it is actually accessing 'external' domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have one DNS server which resolves all local domain names, and in case of failure  it sends request to ISP DNS. So all your dev workstations should have only one DNS server in it's records - your DNS server.

There is also different situation when your DNS server can respond only for local domain names. In this case you need add two DNS records to your dev machines - local DNS as primary, ISP DNS as secondary.

This depends on how you will configure your DNS server.

Comment: Just how do I configure my DNS server, i.e. through which app, specifically to have it resolve domain name entries to a local web site?

Comment: +1 for Andrejs, he is correct. To access DNS on your SBS 2003 server, go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > DNS or from the cmd line %SystemRoot%\system32\dnsmgmt.msc /s

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I finally found it.  Now to find all those DNS for Dummies articles I downloaded months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to edit your hosts file to resolve the domain without a request to any DNS, but the changes will only be applied locally, so it's only an option for dev environments and testing, not for production. In windows, the hosts file is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, but only writable as administrator, on a unix derivative OS it is located at /etc/hosts. Simply add a new entry with "[IP]     [HOST]", for example to make example.cloudflare.dns resolve to 1.1.1.1, append "1.1.1.1     example.cloudflare.dns". This is useful to solve a lot of issues and for testing when dealing with DNS.